# Getting library names from custom LDFLAGS in AutoMake/Autoconf file

Tags: c++, autoconf, automake

I have Makefile.am file which has custom LDFLAGS like -lmbox, -lcsp, .
. etc are defined. C, C++ Sources & libraries are scattered in that system. And it compiles well. How do I get complete path and full name of the libraries associated with each LDFLAG?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? Why do you need the full paths if the project already "builds well"? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I want full library names, to identify the sources associated with. I am a new person to the environment. This info will help me to properly tag the sources.